# Get real screen dimensions in API 24

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I have a singleton class, to whom I pass the context to and which contains the following function:

```
public ScreenResolution getScreenResolution()
{
    ScreenResolution resolution = new ScreenResolution();

    Display display = ((WindowManager) this.context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics realMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getRealMetrics(realMetrics);

    Log.d( "ScreenResolution", realMetrics.toString() );

    return resolution;
}
```

Logcat output:

```
DisplayMetrics{density=2.625, width=1080, height=1920, scaledDensity=2.625, xdpi=386.3655, ydpi=390.144}
```

I have Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge+ (running Android 7.0), which has a screen resolution of 1440x2560, but DisplayMetrics returns 1080x1920.

All the solutions I came across seem to be for older API's only (API 14/17). How can I read the true screen resolution for API 24 and why is it returning a wrong resoution in the first place?

Maybe it's more reliable to read Build.MODEL and cross reference it to a screen resolution table?